# Can not scrape an element in google search although can be seen in view source

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape definition if a word from google search

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=define%20subtle#cns=1

Although all the meanings and examples can be seen when I view the source of the page but still not able to scrape them.

```
<div class="vk_gy">"his language expresses rich and subtle meanings"</div>
```

can be seen in source but soup.find("div", class_='vk_gy') return NONE.

Comment: Are you sure you sure you are looking at the source and not the generated DOM after Javascript has run? Google uses a lot of Javascript and will block you pretty quickly if they suspect you of scraping.

Comment: yes i just did right click on the page and selected view source

Comment: The DOM might also depend on the User-Agent string you are sending to Google. Have you output the DOM in your script and made sure that it looks as expected?

Comment: i cheked the DOM in DOM Inspector AddOn on Firefox and it is there.

Comment: But, you haven't confirmed that you get the same DOM in your Python script, right? You should output it there and double check.

Comment: No, some elements are missing. I don't know why!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128985/discussion-between-ajay-choudhary-and-jsfan).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are loading the complete html string into beautiful soup. How are you grabbing the html? Google does not like you scraping their pages. If you can get the full loaded html into python, you'll find your command should work. This was my output:

```
>>> print(soup.find("div", class_='vk_gy').prettify())
<div class="xpdxpnd vk_gy" data-mh="-1">
 <span>
  adjective:
  <b>
   subtle
  </b>
 </span>
 <span>
  ; comparative adjective:
  <b>
   subtler
  </b>
 </span>
 <span>
  ; superlative adjective:
  <b>
   subtlest
  </b>
 </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.ubHt5c` `CSS` selector, e.g:

```py
examples = soup.select('.ubHt5c')
for example in examples:
   # other code..

# or 
for example in soup.select('.ubHt5c'):
    # other code..

# or list comprehension
examples = [example.text for example in soup.select('.ubHt5c')] # returns a list
```

Make sure you're using `user-agent` because default `requests` `user-agent` is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you'll receive a different HTML with some sort of an error. `User-agent` fakes user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

I wrote a dedicated blog about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping search engines that cover multiple solutions](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/how-to-reduce-chance-being-blocked-while-web-scraping-search-engines-1o46).

Pass `user-agent` in request `headers`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
requests.get('YOUR_URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Multiple-Answer-Box#dictionary_answerbox.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
  'User-agent':
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

params = {
  'q': 'swagger definition',
  'gl': 'us'
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

examples = [example.text for example in soup.select('.ubHt5c')]
print(examples)

# ['"he swaggered along the corridor"', '"they strolled around the camp with an exaggerated swagger"']
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't figure out how to make things work and then maintain it over time, instead you only need to iterate over structured JSON and get the data you want fast.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "swagger definition",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

examples = results['answer_box']['examples']
print(examples)

# # ['"he swaggered along the corridor"', '"they strolled around the camp with an exaggerated swagger"']
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.